# "Filestream type or namespace could not be found" issue with C#

Tags: c#, text-files, filestream, windows-forms-designer

I am working on a program where we need to load text files (book catalogs) for reading and writing (in a Windows Form), so I added "using System.IO", then wrote:

```
FileStream textFile = new Filestream("booklist.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

I was receiving the error "The type or namespace name 'Filestream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". Upon investigation (and attempting the close/reopening of VS2010), I saw someone suggest just writing "System.IO.Filestream" instead of Filestream, and this seems to eliminate the error.

Can someone explain why this worked, and would it create any issues down the road? (still writing the code for the rest now) Thanks

Comment: `Filestream` the 'S' has to be upper case

Comment: ^ totally write, I feel stupid. Thanks!

Comment: I rollbacked the question so everyone can see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to use the `FileStream` class? Please note the upper `S`-letter.

Comment: No need, happened to all of us already. :-) Feel free to mark my answer as correct if it helped you.